# If $A$ is invertible and $F$ is Fredholm, when is $A+F$ also Fredholm?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

We are in the setting of Hilbert spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Let $A:X \to Y$ be a linear bounded and monotone operator which is invertible. Suppose that $F:X \to Y$ is a Fredholm operator.

Under what (general as possible) assumptions on $A$ and $F$ will be find that $A+F$ is also a Fredholm operator?

I know in general sums of Fredholm operators are not Fredholm themselves.

Comment: How would an answer look like? Conditions on $A,F$ so that $A+F$ is Fredholm? Your conditions are not enough, as $F=-A$ shows, for example.

Comment: @s.harp Oh... then yes any conditions would be useful

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $X=Y $ infinite dimensional and $F=-A $, then $A+F=0$ is not Fredholm